# Sending message to specific user using spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, stomp

My Goal - To send message to single user if possible without using spring security

I want to input a username from user and set it as username in spring security so that I can use method  `convertAndSendToUser`. I searched on the net and found two approaches

1. Using `DefaultHandshakeHandler` to set username but this way I am unable to retrieve user input from the page and use it in `determineUser` method
2. I have tried using following piece of code

   `Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("xyz", null);
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(request);`

   But it is not working as it is just changing the username for that method and then it resets the username.
   If possible is there any approach with which I can send message to single user without using spring security. Thanks in advance

P.S. I am a newbee.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your **first approach** to set the Username. First you need add the **interceptor** to your StompEndpointRegistry class and after that you can determine User from the  **attributes** Map and return the **Principal**.

Below is the Code:

**HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor** is Used for Intercepting the Http attributes and provide them in the **DefaultHandshakeHandler** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app","/user");

}

public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat")
     //Method .addInterceptors for enabling interceptor
    .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor())
    .setHandshakeHandler(new MyHandler())
    .withSockJS();
}

class MyHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler{


    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
            Map<String, Object> attributes) {

//Get the Username object which you have saved as session objects

    String name  = (String)attributes.get("name");

 //Return the User
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, null);
    }
  }

}
```