# Spring WebSocket. How to get username via DefaultHandshakeHandler

Tags: spring-websocket

I try to implement sending message to a specific user via Spring WebSocket.

Method from controller

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + username + "/queue/messages", messageDto);
```

But how to get username? As I searched for that need to add DefaultHandshakeHandler to websocket endpoint

I've added:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/chat" allowed-origins="*">
        <websocket:handshake-handler ref="customHandler"/>
        <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /queue" />
```

```
public class CustomDefaultHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
    But attributes is null
     .....
        return principal;
    }
}
```

For example here: [Sending message to specific user using spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333910/sending-message-to-specific-user-using-spring)

```
 String name  = (String)attributes.get("name");
```

But attributes are empty(null).
What should I do to get username attribute?
frontend use Angular4 and stomp over WebSocket service

```
this.stomp.configure({
    host: AppSettings.WEBSOCKET_HOST + '/chat',
    headers: {'username': 'test'},     
    queue:{'init':false}
});
```

Comment: Refer to this answer. It may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47956531/5903344

Comment: @Ivan did you got any solution to this, o man this is 5 years old